# Убрать дубликаты из списка

Tags: java

Задан каркас метода, который должен удалить дубликаты из списка. И тест на него. Как реализовать метод?? Возможно задача простая, но в этом деле я пока новичок.

```
public class FullSearch {
    public static HashSet<String> extractNumber(List<Task> list) {
        HashSet<String> numbers = new HashSet<>();

        // for-each
        return numbers;
    }
}

public class FullSearchTest {

    @Test
    public void extractNumber() {
        List<Task> tasks = Arrays.asList(
                new Task("1", "First desc"),
                new Task("2", "Second desc"),
                new Task("1", "First desc")
        );
        Set<String> expected = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));
        assertThat(FullSearch.extractNumber(tasks), is(expected));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static HashSet<String> extractNumber(List<Task> list) {
    HashSet<String> numbers = new HashSet<>();

    // for-each
    for (Task task : list) {
        numbers.add(task.getNumber());
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```
public static HashSet<String> extractNumber(List<Task> list) {
        HashSet<String> numbers = new HashSet<>();
        list.stream()
                .forEach(n -> numbers.add(n.getFirstVariable()));
        return numbers;
}
```

n.getFirstVariable() здесь должно возвращаться значение поля Task-a, которое у вас указано как "1" или "2", вы не указали как называются ваши поля класса Task, поэтому назвал firstVariable

Comment: как решить без stream. Самый такой простой способ. public class Task {
    private String number;
    private String description;


    public Task(String number, String description) {
        this.number = number;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}

Comment: Так что в итоге должно оказаться в numbers? Уникальные номера или неуникальные? И нужно ли из исходного списка удалять что-то? (в условии так написано, что нужно удалить дубликаты)

Comment: в numbers должны быть уникальные имена.

Comment: @RasimZamaltdinov Вы хотели сказать НОМЕРА

Comment: да,в предыдущем комментарии опечатка